# Add / Show comment with less than 50 reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, comments

If a user has less than 50 reputation, it is known that they cannot comment on posts other than their own.

I've been in a situtaion, (this applies to the wider stack exchange interface) where I have been writing an answer to a question and the page has been commented on by other users. In a attempt to get the most up to date information, I go to click on add / show X new comments. But I can't.

I get the feeling this is a result of having less than 50 rep and so the comment feature is disabled but I don't want to comment, I just want to read the updated information as its coming in without have to reload the page and lose the answer I'm working on.

Now that I have more than 50 rep (just) and I can comment on other posts, the problem no longer exists.

Can someone else with less than 50 rep confirm this? I've seen in on StackOverflow, SuperUser and Electrical Engineering so far.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug.

Comment: Does this *only*
 happen when the comments are added *while you're writing an answer* (that is, you're notified of them via the live update feature)?

Comment: @Shog9 Correct. Under normal circumstances, the page loads with the comments visible. When the number of comments are truncated due to the quantity of them, I had no trouble expanding the list then. Nice point to clarify. :)

Comment: Good - I've reproduced this & passed it along.

Comment: Excellent. A better experience can be had by others and I'm not crazy. Win for everyone. If its proven and fix, will it be propagated to the other stack exchange sites or should I post on their metas too? Not that I want to spam them or anything.

Comment: @SLaG Bug fixes will be propagated to all SE sites (all changes that aren't site specific are). This report was sufficient.

Comment: I think I know what's causing this.  I should be able to get to it soon.